# How to Create a SQLAlchemy Data Engine to Export Pandas DF to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Just as a disclaimer, I'm very new to Python and using it primarily to work on fun projects involving SQL. With that being said, let's dive in.

Goal: To create a script that will read data from a CSV file stored locally on my workstation, and then inject that data directly into a Microsoft SQL Server DB. Currently, I'm web scraping data that's being saved in an excel file, then creating a DF of the data using Pandas. From there I want to export the data into my DB.

Tools: Currently using Python 3.7 32 bit, SQL Server version 11.0.2100.60, SSMS 17,  and Windows 64 bit OS.

Code being used in Py:

```
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\NameofFile.csv', encoding = 'latin1')

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://DESKTOP-0000\SQLEXPRESS/NameofDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0')

df.to_sql('NameofTable',engine)
```

Problem:

I get the following error when running this code:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Now I've tried looking into ODBC data sources in Administrative tools and adding SQL server to the 32 bit user DSN. I also noticed when viewing the 64bit ODBC, it shows SQL Server with platform 32/64 bit under User DSN. I think that the way I'm declaring the connection is wrong, but I can't figure out how to properly declare the connection for MSSQL. I can only seem to find prime examples for MYSQL and SQLLite, but I want to use MSSQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this is because your connection URL is wrong. I don't know enough about ODBC to know what it should be, but SQLAlchemy is looking for `mssql+pymssql://username:password@hostname:port/dbname`, more or less

Comment: You can use `pyodbc` but in this format: `mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@server/database`